# .expect( format!() ): expected `&str`, found struct `String`

Tags: rust, macros

I tried to create a macro that replaces,

```
first: Some(first.as_ref().parse::<u64>().expect("Could not parse 'first'"))
```

I've seen this done in other modules like [Clap with `values_t!`](https://docs.rs/clap/2.33.0/clap/macro.values_t.html), my attempt to abstract this doesn't extend to types. I wrote this,

```rust
macro_rules! parse_u64 {
  ($var:ident) => {
    Some(
      $var
      .as_ref()
      .parse::<u64>()
      .expect(  format!("Could not parse '{:?}'", stringify!($var))  )
    ) 
  };
}
```

This produces the following error,

```rust
first: parse_u64!(first),
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `&str`, found struct `String`
```

What am I doing wrong here: this is a simple macro with only three things in the chain? Why do I get this error and how can I fix it?

---

You can see this in this [Rust Playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ee6f0c8b3b3574d2bee4cda1fcbace5f)

Comment: Panicking on input errors makes my Spidey-sense tingle. Try not to make a habit of it. It's better to propagate errors with `?` and such, like Clap does. Since you're creating an `Option<u64>`, might I suggest [`parse::<u64>().ok()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.ok)?

Comment: @JohnKugelman without the Macro, I assume Rust would have told me where the expect was instead when it said, _"expected `&str`, found struct `String`"_ I was trying to create a macro when someone immediately answered it in Discord. I guess it's a common problem?

Comment: @JohnKugelman I just got it! there we go https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=510924b55e94487f2d955fc26e26ce0f

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As you mentioned in your own answer, `expect` takes a `&str` so you can't pass in a `String` directly:

```rust
.expect(format!("Could not parse '{:?}'", stringify!($var)).as_str())
```

However, this will perform string formatting (and allocate a new string) even if there was no error, so instead I would propose this:

```rust
.unwrap_or_else(|err| panic!("Could not parse '{:?}': {}", stringify!($var), err))
```

This is effectively the same as the above, expect that [`unwrap_or_else`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/core/result/enum.Result.html#method.unwrap_or_else) only invokes its closure in the error case.

---

Alternatively, in this specific case you can concatenate string literals at compile-time with [`concat!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/macro.concat.html), which also avoids the cost of `format!`:

```rust
.expect(concat!("Could not parse '", stringify!($var), "'"))
```

Comment: Nice suggestion for `unwrap_or_else()`, but please format the error with `{}`, not with `{:?}`. The latter will provide a user-unfriendly representation of the error type with its internal fields, instead of the user-facing error message.

Answer (score -1):

The problem I was having was

```
.expect(  format!("Could not parse '{:?}'", stringify!($var))  )
```

Should have been,

```
.expect(  format!("Could not parse '{:?}'", stringify!($var)).as_str()  )
```

[format!](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.format.html) creates a `String`, and [`.expect()` takes a `&str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.expect)

---

Thanks to [MEOW RAX, Nyathark Shill](https://discord.com/channels/273534239310479360/274215136414400513/896946799351312424) on Discord.

Comment: Or `&format!(...)`.